# How to create bitmap with Pillow from image without saving image?

Tags: python, image, bitmap, python-imaging-library

Currently I use

```
im.save(save_img)
out_book.get_sheet(0).insert_bitmap(save_img, 0, 0)
```

to insert a bitmap into an excel sheet.

I tried to convert my image to a bitmap using

```
im = Image.tobitmap(image_name)
```

but I get `AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'tobitmap'`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748822/img-image-openfp-attributeerror-class-image-has-no-attribute-open/10749029) but trying that did not fix my problem. This is a fresh windows install and a fresh virtualenv where there was never PIL only pillow 4.3.0. Also I found the tobitmap in my source files of pillow and it is in the documentation online. Strangely I can use

```
im = Image.open(image_name).convert("RGB")
im.thumbnail((533, 70))
im.save(save_img)
out_book.get_sheet(0).insert_bitmap(save_img, 0, 0)
```

but not tobitmap, any ideas?

EDIT: Of course I could delete the temporary saved file after inserting, but this is not really a pythonic/good way of doing things.

Comment: What type of argument will `insert_bitmap()` accept? Perhaps it has to be the name/path of a file.

Comment: insert_bitmap takes a filepath, but how is that relevant to the error I am getting?

Comment: pillow is a fork of PIL, the Python Image Library. It's mostly backwards compatible, but it does have additional features like supporting Python 3 and bug fixes. BTW, the `Image.tobitmap()` method only works on bitmapped images (1-bit-per-pixel, aka `mode='1'`).

Comment: It's relevant because it requires you to create a file to pass to it.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. If you make it an answer I can accept it. Silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `from PIL import Image`—as you should be when using the pillow library—then afterwards `Image` will be the name of the module, which has no attribute or function named `tobitmap`. You're probably confused because there is also a class within that module and it is also named `Image`, and instances of that class **do** have a `tobitmap()` method you can try to use.

Bottom-line: You need to call `Image.open()` or otherwise create an `Image.Image` *instance* then you can call its `tobitmap()` method.

That said, I don't think it will help avoid having to save the image to a file before calling `out_book.get_sheet(0).insert_bitmap()` because, from what you said in a comment, it sounds like the `insert_bitmap()` method will accept a file/path argument (in other words, the name of a *file*, not something which is only stored in memory.

Comment: The last part is especially relevant. Don't know how I didn't realise this earlier. So yes, I guess I have to leave it the way it is right now.

Comment: That fact that there's both module and class named `Image` _is_ definitely confusing. To help with what you're trying to accomplish, consider using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` to create a temporary file with a name to pass to `insert_bitmap()`. Be sure to specify `delete=False` so it won't automatically be deleted when it's closed (just do it yourself sometime after the call to insert it). There's an example of using it (to solve a different problem) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30400531/355230) of mine.